# Python "map": Do I have to surround it with "list"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I find that sometimes, if I want to use the result of Python `map`, I have to surround the call with `list`.  For example:

```
>>> sum(map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5)))
15
>>> max(map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5)))
5
>>> map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5))[2:3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

What I'm looking for is some rule that defines when the addition of `list` is necessary.

Comment: I understand iterators and I understand map objects.   What I'm *trying* to understand is, why does "sum" and "list" apply to a map object, while "index" does not.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> help(map)
Help on class map in module builtins:

class map(object)
 |  map(func, *iterables) --> map object
 |
 |  Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
 |  each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

here in  `map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5))[2:3]` ,

`map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5))` will create an iteratable object, on which you can iteratre (with loop or iter func). you cannot do list slicing on this part `[2:3]`.

to do list slicing, you need to first iterate over this iterable and then save it into list/tuple and then do slicing.

so since you are, directly using list slicing on this, you are facing this error `TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable`

so solution will be first store data in list/tuple by iterating over the map object and then doing slicing

```
# using list
list(map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5)))[2:3]

# using tuple
tuple(map( lambda x: x + 1, range(5)))[2:3]
```